# generator-angular-fullstack : how to run just the Server

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, angular-fullstack

Normally you start the whole application with the typical:

```
grunt serve
```

But this starts up the whole application, with sass compiling, etc.

Is there anyway to just start up the server side? I must be missing something! I'd love to be able to work on the Api portion and test it quickly without having to have the whole app start up.

```
grunt serve-server // or something random like that?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not as you expect, out of the box. You can create a new task in `gruntfile.js` that run the needed tasks but not others, or you can simply run

```
node server.js
```

that will run the app without running any grunt task.

Comment: oh that's perfect! As long as I can test the Api / mongo schemes etc this will help so much! I'll look into a new grunt task as well, have live reload in this case would be a nice bonus. Thanks again Remi. Somehow I forgot the standard Node commands still work haha

Comment: You're welcome. Your new grunt task shoud for example just registering `watch:server-js`